# JAVA Comma separated string to single quoted string

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get the values from the user and using those values in my SQL query.
I'm able to append the single values in my query but when I'm using IN in my query I'm facing problem.

I'm getting a string from user : `po1,po2,po3`.
I want to convert it into `'po1','po2','po3'` with least changes in the previous code.

I already handled adding brackets for IN but facing problem for adding single quotes.

Here's my whole code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String poListString = "po1,po2,po3";
    String query = "SELECT shpUID.attribute_value                               shipunitid,         pal.container_id                                     palletid,         cas.container_id                                     caseid,         dl.delivery_line_id,        dg.delivery_group_id,        dlv.delivery_type_id,        dl.qty,        po.attribute_value                                   po,         Max(Isnull(comm.attribute_value, ''))                commodity,         Sum(Isnull(Cast(wgt.attribute_value AS FLOAT), 0.0)) weight,         Max(Isnull(wgtuom.attribute_value, ''))                weightuom,         Sum(Isnull(Cast(vol.attribute_value AS FLOAT), 0.0)) volume,       Max(Isnull(voluom.attribute_value, ''))                volumeuom,         GETDATE()                                         EventDate FROM   container pal         INNER JOIN container cas                 ON pal.container_id = cas.parent_container_id                    AND pal.container_type = 'Pallet'                    AND cas.container_type = 'Case'         INNER JOIN container_detail cdtl                 ON cdtl.container_id = cas.container_id         INNER JOIN container_delivery cd                 ON cd.detail_id = cdtl.detail_id         INNER JOIN delivery_line dl                 ON cd.delivery_line_id = dl.delivery_line_id         INNER JOIN delivery_group dg                 ON dg.delivery_group_id = dl.delivery_group_id        INNER JOIN delivery dlv                 ON dlv.delivery_num = dl.delivery_num         INNER JOIN delivery_type dt                 ON dt.delivery_type_id = dlv.delivery_type_id        LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute shpUID                      ON shpUID.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id                         AND shpUID.attribute_type = 'SHIP_UNIT_ID'         LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute wgt                      ON wgt.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id                         AND wgt.attribute_type = 'Weight'         LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute wgtuom                      ON wgtuom.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id                         AND wgtuom.attribute_type = 'Weightuom'        LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute vol                      ON vol.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id                         AND vol.attribute_type = 'Volume'                LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute voluom                      ON voluom.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id                         AND voluom.attribute_type = 'Volumeuom'         LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute comm                      ON comm.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id                         AND comm.attribute_type = 'COMMODITY'         LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute po                      ON po.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id                         AND po.attribute_type = 'PO'  WHERE           pal.container_id = @REPLACEMENT-1@  AND             dlv.delivery_num                  IN @REPLACEMENT-IN@  AND             dt.class = @REPLACEMENT-2@  GROUP  BY pal.container_id,            cas.container_id,            dl.delivery_line_id,            shpUID.attribute_value,            po.attribute_value,           pal.container_type,           dg.delivery_group_id,           dlv.delivery_type_id,           dl.qty UNION  SELECT shpUID.attribute_value                               shipunitid,         pal.container_id                                     palletid,         'UNKNOWN'                                            caseid,        dl.delivery_line_id,         dg.delivery_group_id,       dlv.delivery_type_id,      dl.qty,        po.attribute_value                                   po,         Max(Isnull(comm.attribute_value, ''))                commodity,         Sum(Isnull(Cast(wgt.attribute_value AS FLOAT), 0.0)) weight,         Max(Isnull(wgtuom.attribute_value, ''))                weightuom,         Sum(Isnull(Cast(vol.attribute_value AS FLOAT), 0.0)) volume,        Max(Isnull(voluom.attribute_value, ''))                volumeuom,         GETDATE()                                           EventDate FROM   container pal         INNER JOIN container_detail cdtl                 ON cdtl.container_id = pal.container_id                    AND pal.container_type = 'Pallet'         INNER JOIN container_delivery cd                 ON cd.detail_id = cdtl.detail_id         INNER JOIN delivery_line dl                 ON cd.delivery_line_id = dl.delivery_line_id         INNER JOIN delivery_group dg                   ON dg.delivery_group_id = dl.delivery_group_id        INNER JOIN delivery dlv                 ON dlv.delivery_num = dl.delivery_num         INNER JOIN delivery_type dt                 ON dt.delivery_type_id = dlv.delivery_type_id        LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute shpUID                      ON shpUID.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id                         AND shpUID.attribute_type = 'SHIP_UNIT_ID'         LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute wgt                      ON wgt.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id                         AND wgt.attribute_type = 'Weight'         LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute wgtuom                      ON wgtuom.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id                         AND wgtuom.attribute_type = 'Weightuom'        LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute vol                      ON vol.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id                         AND vol.attribute_type = 'Volume'           LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute voluom                      ON voluom.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id                         AND voluom.attribute_type = 'Volumeuom'         LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute comm                      ON comm.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id                         AND comm.attribute_type = 'COMMODITY'         LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute po                      ON po.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id                         AND po.attribute_type = 'PO'  WHERE           pal.container_id = @REPLACEMENT-1@  AND             dlv.delivery_num                  IN @REPLACEMENT-IN@  AND             dt.class = @REPLACEMENT-2@  GROUP  BY pal.container_id,            dl.delivery_line_id,            shpUID.attribute_value,            po.attribute_value,           pal.container_type,           dg.delivery_group_id,           dlv.delivery_type_id,           dl.qty";
    String value1 = "12345678910";
    String value2 = "INBOUND";

    String finalQuery = AppendQueryForIN.generateDynamicQueryForInAndValue(query, poListString, value1, value2);
    System.out.println(finalQuery);

}

public static String generateDynamicQueryForInAndValue(String sqlQuery, String stringList, String value1, String value2)
{
    StringBuilder listWithBrackets = new StringBuilder();
    listWithBrackets = listWithBrackets.append('(').append(stringList).append(')');
    String value1WithQoutes = "'"+value1+"'";
    String value2WithQoutes = "'"+value2+"'";
    String finalQuery = sqlQuery.replace("@REPLACEMENT-IN@", listWithBrackets);
    finalQuery = finalQuery.replace("@REPLACEMENT-1@", value1WithQoutes);
    finalQuery = finalQuery.replace("@REPLACEMENT-2@", value2WithQoutes);
    return finalQuery;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static String generateDynamicQueryForInAndValue(String sqlQuery, String stringList, String value1, String value2)
    {
        StringBuilder listWithBrackets = new StringBuilder();
        if(stringList == null || stringList.isEmpty()){
            stringList = "''";
        }else{

        stringList=stringList.replaceAll("^|$", "'").replaceAll(",", "','"); 
        }
        listWithBrackets = listWithBrackets.append('(').append(stringList).append(')');
        String value1WithQoutes = "'"+value1+"'";
        String value2WithQoutes = "'"+value2+"'";
         String finalQuery = sqlQuery.replace("@REPLACEMENT-IN@", listWithBrackets);
         finalQuery = finalQuery.replace("@REPLACEMENT-1@", value1WithQoutes);
         finalQuery = finalQuery.replace("@REPLACEMENT-2@", value2WithQoutes);
        return finalQuery;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that string format doesn't change, you can use `regex` to replace comma and start and end of the string

For example:

```
    String poListString = "po1,po2,po3";
    String result=poListString.replaceAll("^|$", "'").replaceAll(",", "','"); 
    //first replaceAll, adds ' to start and end and second replace change , to ','
    System.out.println(results);
```

**OUTPUT:**

> 'po1','po2','po3'

Comment: This fails if user sends empty poListString. Though I can handle it separately but is there any way to handle it within your code? @nafas

Comment: @Siddharth I did mention assuming input's format doesn't change, you have a hack around it though : `result= results.replaceAll("''","");` which will clear up the string if it ever was empty. (its a hack, its a hack, its a hack)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `String.split`:

```
String poListString = "po1,po2,po3";
String[] parts = poListString.split(",");
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

for (String part : parts) {
    if (output.length() > 0) {
        output.append(",");
    }

    output.append("'").append(part).append("'");
}

System.out.println(output);
```

**Output:**

```
'po1','po2','po3'
```

Comment: It's better to use `StringBuilder` instead of `+`. Also in Java 8 there's [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html).

Comment: @MarounMaroun Java uses `StringBuilder` under the hood to handle all `String` manipulations (as Strings are immutable).

Comment: For long concatenation, there's a big difference in performance.

Comment: Point taken, and I'll assume that using a single `StringBuilder` would win out in such a case, because using raw `String` concatenation would require creating a chain of `StringBuilder`s.

Answer (score 0):

Just for sharing the idea by using a `Stream`.

```
String quoted = Pattern.compile(",").splitAsStream(poListString)
                                    .collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'"));
```

By storing the `Pattern` as a constant in your class and using static import:

```
String quoted = PATTERN.splitAsStream(poListString).collect(joining("','", "'", "'"));
```